# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-maps-api-3

My app allows the user to find their current location on the press of the button.Whenever the app is started for the first time, it asks for the user permission but it crashes when the permission is granted giving following logcat error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: com.shubhamsharma.idonate, PID: 17404
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.shubhamsharma.idonate/com.shubhamsharma.idonate.iDonate}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4123)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4166)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1562)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6237)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.shubhamsharma.idonate.iDonate.onRequestPermissionsResult(iDonate.java:165)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7263)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7115)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4119)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4166) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1562) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6237) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

the flow is like this
MAIN ACTIVITY(Takes login id and password and checks it from firebase)---> then comes the idonate Activity which ask for the permission and then crashes

My MAIN ACTIVITY code

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button login, register;
EditText email,password;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



    firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, iDonate.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return;

            }
        }


    };

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String log= email.getText().toString();
            final String pas= password.getText().toString();
            if(log.length()!=0 && pas.length()!=0) {
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(log, pas).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            String userid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(userid);
                            current_user_db.setValue(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Id or Password cannot be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                email.setText("");
                password.setText("");

            }
        }
    });

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String log = email.getText().toString();
            final String pas = password.getText().toString();
            if(log.length()!=0 && pas.length()!=0) {
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(log, pas).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful())
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signup Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, iDonate.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Id or Password cannot be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                email.setText("");
                password.setText("");
            }
        }
    });


}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);

}
```

}

idonate code below

```
public class iDonate extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private Button mlogout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_i_donate);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mlogout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.logout);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(iDonate.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
      //  return;
        } else {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        }


        mlogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(iDonate.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
          //  return;
        }

        buildGoogleApiClient();
         mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);




    }


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){


        mGoogleApiClient= new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();


    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(iDonate.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation=location;
        LatLng latLng=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));

      String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
      DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversAvailable");

        GeoFire geoFire  = new GeoFire(ref);
        geoFire.setLocation(userId,new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));


    }

    final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(grantResults[0]), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
             //   break;
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow your GPS Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
              //  return;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean hasAllPermissionsGranted(@NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
            if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        FirebaseUser userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();/////////////////////////////
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversAvailable");
     //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),userId.getUid(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
        geoFire.removeLocation(userId.getUid());
       // return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

mapFragment.getMapAsync(this) is return null so check that class